# Al intentar subir a la rama remota, aparece Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Tags: git, push, pull

Quiero subir mi rama local a mi rama remota, pero pasa lo contrario la rama remota viene a mi rama local.
Primero hize "git add ." --> Crear una copia
luego un commit (con una carga de 4 actualizaciones) y cuando estoy listo para subir a la rama remota, mediante un push, me arroja esto

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes

Y cuando hago un pull, ahí es cuando se vienen los archivos del remoto (cerca de 16 archivos)

Lo que yo quiero es que mi archivo local, se suba a mi rama remota y reemplace todo lo que hay ahí, y que esos 16 archivos, se reemplacen por los 4 que tengo ahí.

Comment: Usa `git status` para saber qué cambios tienes en local. Por otro lado, si quieres eliminar entonces elimina esos archivos en local (luego usa git status si quieres saber qué archivos has eliminado, modificado o creado) y ejecuta git add, git commit y git push como sueles hacer

Comment: Como bien dices deberías traerte los cambios con git pull y luego editar lo que quieras local y subirlo. Borrar los 16 files y subir los nuevos, lo que necesites. Si no quieres traerte nada (no lo recomiendo), podrías forzar el push con el argumento force, pero estarías perdiendo commits de tu historia

Comment: Si quieres que se reemplacen, simplemente haz un `git push -f`, y te cargas el remoto machacándolo con lo que tienes ahora mismo en el local. Eso si, cuidado que es destructivo, puedes perder cosas.